# "resolvectl dns" gives empty output

Tags: networking, server, dns, resolv.conf, domain-server

I do on my VPS with Ubuntu 22 server (new, clean setup):

```
root@vm905709:~# resolvectl dns ens3
Link 2 (ens3):
root@vm905709:~#
```

(BTW, I did it on the same VPS with Debian and it was the same.)

And Global:

```
root@vm905709:~# resolvectl dns
Global: 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
Link 2 (ens3):
root@vm905709:~#
```

You see, there is nothing after "Link 2 (ens3):", but a WireGuard setup guide says:

> You should receive output like the following:
>
> ```
> Link 2 (eth0): 67.207.67.2 67.207.67.3 2001:4860:4860::8844 2001:4860:4860::8888
> ```

I tried to do the same in my local qemu virtual machine with Ubuntu 22 server for test, and it has showed an IP after "Link 2 (ens3):". So on local virtual machine it works, but on remote server (VPS) it doesn't. Why? And do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `ens3` and `eth0` are different.  Show the configuration on the remote server - the WireGuard *server* won't have a DNS set on its link typically, especially if the VPS is a statically-configured system.

Comment: Which configuration I need to show? (It's a brand new Ubuntu server 22 machine).

From guide: "If you are using the WireGuard Server as a VPN gateway for all your peer’s traffic, you will need to add a line to the [Interface] section that specifies DNS resolvers. If you do not add this setting, then your DNS requests may not be secured by the VPN, or they might be revealed to your Internet Service Provider or other third parties."

Comment: and when I do "resolvectl dns ens3" on my local virtual machine (qemu), I have proper output, something like this:
" Link 2 (ens3): 10.0.1.2 fuc1::2 "